# How to solve this differential equation? and what type is it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would like to know what kind of differential equation is this? A linear ODE, a nonlinear DE, etc? And also what will be the ways of solving it?

$$
\frac{dT(t)}{dt} + A\sqrt{T(t)}\cdot(T(t)-B) + C\cdot (T(t)+D)^4 = E + F(GT(t)+H)
$$

I have seen in the books that the equation is solved as an ODE by linearising the $T^4(t)$ term and making it separable.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that $f_1$, etc., are functions of $T$, not of $t$? Because then, if we do not know what $f_1$ etc. are, there are no general methods of finding a solution in closed form (only abstract theorems on the existence (and possibly uniqueness) of an initial value problem).

Comment: So if $f_1$ = $1+2T^2(t)+3T^3(t)$, should I say it is a function of $f_1(T)$ or $f_1(t)$?

Comment: @user401393 As a function of $T$.

Comment: Such an $f_1$ is a function of $T$.

Comment: So, my first comment applies: without knowing the form of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ nothing sure can be said.

Comment: I see, I'll grab the book and write down the expressions when I get back to my institute.

Comment: No linearization is needed: the equation is already separable.  However, the resulting integrals may or may not be doable in closed form, depending on the forms of $f_1, f_2, f_3$.

Comment: Is it then just a linear ODE?

Comment: No, not at all linear; it is a separable (autonomous) equation, of the form $T'(t)=g(T(t))$. If you need a closed form, the problem is in finding the inverse function of $\int\frac{dT}{g(T)}$.

Comment: When the book solved it by linearising $T^4(t)$ and putting it in linear ODE form, is that a correct solution approach?

Comment: It's the $\sqrt{T(t)}$ term that makes the equation nonlinear

Comment: @user401393 Linearizing an equation is a standard procedure, but if the original equation is nonlinear (as in you case) then a solution of the linearized equation cannot be a correct solution of the problem from the point of view of a **mathematician**. Having said that, this is a "first approximation" which can give us (even a pure mathematician) a lot of insight. Also, sometimes in practice it suffices to solve the linearized equation only (but that depends on the problem).